# Jquery syntax error

Tags: jquery, testing

Ok, I'm very simply trying to take this example... http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/HGF59/ and put it on a test page on my own server to play with. I've got another jquery bit of code that works fine on another page, am I missing something very obvious here?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>jQuery demo</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
    var areas = [{
        value: "area1",
        label: "Area 1",
        desc: "Area 1 extended description"},
    {
        value: "sample2",
        label: "Sample 2",
        desc: "Sample of the second area"},
    {
        value: "third-area",
        label: "Third Area",
        desc: "This is the third area"}];

    var projects = [{
        value: "jquery",
        label: "jQuery",
        desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
        id: 1
    },   {
        value: "jquery-ui",
        label: "jQuery UI",
        desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
        id: 2
    },    {
        value: "sizzlejs",
        label: "Sizzle JS",
        desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
        id: 3
    }];

    $("#areas").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: areas,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#areas").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#project-div").show();
            return false;
        }
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
    };

    $("#project").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: projects,
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#project").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#project").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#project-id").val(ui.item.id);
            $("#project-description").html(ui.item.desc);
            alert("I could submit form with id " + ui.item.id);
            return false;
        }
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
    };
});   


     </script>


</head>

<body>



<div class="demo">     
    <label>Choose area:</label>     
    <input id="areas" />   
    <br />
        <div id="project-div" style="display: none;">
    <label>Choose project:</label>
    <input id="project" />     
    <input type="hidden" id="project-id" />     
    <p id="project-description"></p>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The page is called test.html and it resides in the same folder as jquery-1.7.1.js. Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us what the problem actually is?

Comment: The console does not show any syntax error, so what is the actual problem? What is this code supposed to do anyway? More information is needed.

Comment: video_idT=mV[0]. mV has not been set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code above includes links to the jQuery-UI stylesheets, but not to the jQuery-UI JavaScript. (While you're at it, why not link to the Google Code versions instead? Everybody else does.)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- this goes first -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> <!-- this goes next -->
```

Comment: This worked but why didn't this reference work? <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script> It's included in the same directory? Thanks!

Comment: The problem wasn't how you linked to jQuery; the problem was that you didn't link to jQuery-UI after that. They are two separate files.

Answer (score 0):

Seems everything is OK here..
Make sure your jQuery UI script is included and to be under jQuery.js

Comment: I used this <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script> in the header which correctly points to the version i have residing in the same folder.

Comment: Does the jQuery UI included too?